# Constrain inline-block element's width to fit parent's for ellipsis

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have an ellipsis effect on text contained into an inline-block element.

- It **HAS** to be an "inline-block" element
- The "width" can **ONLY** be set on its parent

Here is the **HTML** :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="line">This is a much tooooooooooooooooo long line</div>
</div>
```

And the **CSS** :

```
.container {
    border: solid 1px black;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}

.icon {
    border: solid 1px blue;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}

.line {
    border: solid 1px red;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

See. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/limax84/h0jz0xj2/5/)

Of course it works by setting a width on the line or by setting its display to block, but this is a no-no for my use case. I'm stuck there, any idea ?

Edit: Oh, I should have specified that the begining of the line is supposed to have some other inline-block elements (actually indentation and icon for a treeview) therefore, the width of the text container cannot be 100% of its parent...

Comment: Can you use `max-width`? **Edit** Ninja'd. @Alexander Dayan has a good solution if you can use `max-width`... You could also do a `width: inherit` if you don't want to set a static width on `line`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do it using  **display: inline-flex** in the container, without any need to use the `display` attribute with the `icon` and the `line`:

```css
.container {
    border: solid 1px black;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.icon {
    border: solid 1px blue;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}

.line {
    border: solid 1px red;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="line">This is a much tooooooooooooooooo long line</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The "display-flex" solution seems to do the trick. However it induce some weird behaviour in my overall layout, but I'll dig into it. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```css
.container {
    border: solid 1px black;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}

.line {
    border: solid 1px red;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="line">This is a much tooooooooooooooooo long line</div>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

For the case with icon on left you can use calc as following:

```css
.container {
    border: solid 1px black;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}

.icon {
    border: solid 1px blue;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}

.line {
    border: solid 1px red;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: calc(100% - 16px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="line">This is a much tooooooooooooooooo long line</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, I should have specified that the begining of the line is supposed to have some other inline-block elements (actually indentation and icon for a treeview) therefore, the width of the text container cannot be 100% of its parent... (I updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/limax84/h0jz0xj2/5/))

Comment: If you don't use the border you can use a negative margin with a text indent set to the width of the icon: `.line{...margin-left: -16px; text-indent: 16px;}` Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h0jz0xj2/6/)

Comment: @HJ05 But the width of the beginning of the line is not fixed and won't always be hard codded "16px". So I need a way to constrain the width of this line element to it's parent's...

Comment: @AlexanderDayan Thanks, I'll keep the "calc" function in mind. However, as I said, the width of the beginning of the line is dynamic.